# mobi file on Kindle - MacPro & MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-pro, kindle, ibook

I bought an electronic book.  I downloaded the mobi version of the book.  And loaded it into my kindle-macPro.  Started reading it, highlighting, etc...worked great.

Then I wanted to read the book on my macbook.  Opened up kindle on my macbook and the book wasn't there.  So, I copied the file from my kindle directory, loaded into kindle, it opened up, but it didn't have any of my hightlights.

I do not own a kindle device.

Is there an easier way for me to share the book across multiple machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/mac?tag=vglnk-c43-20) program from Amazon for synchronization.
It has options to send to other devices (like your macs.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  You know, I think it worked.  I still don't see my high-lights showing up.  But at least it is remembering my last read-position.  Over the weekend, I'll clean-up kindle and try again...will post my findings.